# Is it posible to create a virtual entity in MS Dynamics CRM 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, entity, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

the customer entity in MS Dynamics CRM is not a "normal" entity. It is a virtual composite entity. The question is... Is it posible to create a own virtual entity? And if so how?

I want to create different contract entities and it would be nice to have just the contractid which can be one of a bunch of different contractids. So if there exists a xcontract entity and a ycontract entity and a field where I can insert a contractid it is possible to insert a xcontractid or a ycontractid. Just like it is solved with the customerid and the accountid/contactid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options that may be able to resolve what you're asking.  I'll make a base assumption first, based on your question to help confine my answer.

Assumption:  You desire Entity A to have a single relationship to either Entity B or Entity C

**Option 1 - Custom Joining Entity**

Not sure if this achieves the end result you are looking for, but you could Create Entity D, that has an Entity B and Entity C field, and then create a relationship from Entity A to Entity D.  Entity D would be your "Customer" and Entity B & C would be your account and contact respectively.  You'd have to write a few plugins to ensure the relationship is accurate, and to properly update the display name of Entity D, when it changes for the related Entity B or C records.

**Option 2 - Activity Party**

Assuming Entities B & C have yet to be created, create them as Custom Activities.  You can then select them from an activity party list in the client.  You could also add pre-filters that constrain the activity types that are being queried when the user attempts to lookup an existing record.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that in any versions of Microsoft Dynamics CRM. We all want to have this kind of polymorphic relationships. You can vote for this feature on Connect - https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/Feedback/Details/685374

Comment: Ok thanks, but is it posible to do something similar to this? It would be really nice

Comment: I believe I already answered your question. I can quote myself - There is no way of doing that in any versions of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.